# Profinet connection between PC and PLC S7 1200

Tags: communication, ethernet, plc

I am trying to create a communication between PC and S7 1200 PLC via Profinet. I have researched many web sites and I could not find any information for me. According to the research, I should use GSD file but this file does not exist in Siemens page. How can i create this file? Mainly can I create a communication between PC and S7 1200 via Profinet without external component? All comments and suggestions are appreciated! Thanks in advance.

Comment: So, you want to do this with Profibus, "without external component"; would that include a Profibus card for the PC? What SCADA software package are you using? Does it include Profibus drivers?

Comment: At the physical level Profinet just requires an Ethernet connection, so no additional hardware needed. What software are you using on the PC? TIA Portal?

Comment: @Tyler I did not get your comment. I am working of Profinet. I do not use any SCADA software.

Comment: @NMF I am using TIA Portal v16 but there is no enough information about how to do connection etc. Additionally, I do not have GSD file.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you're looking for OPC-UA. Below is a link to the OPC Foundation website with more detail. I don't know if this satisfies the "without external component" requirement, but it is the standard for sending and receiving data in the industrial space.

[What is OPC?](https://opcfoundation.org/about/what-is-opc/)

Comment: Unfortunately, I cannot use external component, software too. But thanks for reply.